# Сборка проекта с javafx

Tags: javafx, maven

После сборки проекта, как через стандартные средства ide (intellij idea), так и с помощью сборщика Maven, после запуска джарника все в порядке, пока не наступает момент переключения окна. Возникает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at Controller.LogInController.logInButton(LogInController.java:59)
        at Controller.LogInController$1.handle(LogInController.java:41)
        at Controller.LogInController$1.handle(LogInController.java:37)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Если требуется какая-то дополнительная информация скажите, что необходимо прислать?

Дополнительная информация:
[image: Структура проекта]

Место установки в классе LogInController:

```
public class LogInController {
    @FXML
    private TextField user;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField password;
    @FXML
    private Label errorPass;
    @FXML
    private Button logInButton;
    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        password.setText("1");
        user.setText("1");
        KeyCodeCombination kComb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);
        logInButton.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
                    logInButton();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    public void logInButton() {
        User.getUserRole(user.getText(), password.getText());
        if (User.USER != null) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) user.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader =  new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../View/MainMenu.fxml"));
                loader.setController(new MainMenuController());
                Parent pane = loader.load();
                Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
                Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
                primaryStage.setMinHeight(640);
                primaryStage.setMinWidth(920);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            errorPass.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.devcolibri.mavenjavafxapp.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>NewMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
                <version>8.40.11</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в установке пути fxml файла. Нужно место установки и структура проекта

Comment: Дополнил информацию.

Comment: Вроде все верно задано. Пробуйте дебагом посмотреть что происходит с путем, который в FXMLLoader передаете.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, причем тут дебаг?
В среде разработки все работает.
В мавен из консоли я запускаю, все работает.
Но стоит собрать проект в исполняемый файл через артефакт->билд или мавеном (mvn package), то после запуска приложения после авторизации(когда нужно переключить окно) возникает ошибка. Как то же путь до первого он нашел.

Comment: Проверку сделал уже в собранном файле, при переключении loader.getLocation() = null

Answer (score 0):

Что бы загрузить следующий фрейм нужно использовать определение пути иначе:
Не так: 
"../View/MainMenu.fxml"
А вот так:
"/View/MainMenu.fxml"